# Group List<Person> by properties and get number of times grouped

Tags: c#, list, properties, linq-group

Lets say I have a class called Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of persons:

```
Person { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe" }
Person { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe" }
Person { Age = 10, FirstName = "James", LastName = "Dokes" }
```

What I want to have is a (new or old with a new property) list that groups the person by age, first name and last name AND I also want to know how many times that object has been grouped.

So the result of the above would be:

```
Person { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe", Count = 2 }
Person { Age = 10, FirstName = "James", LastName = "Dokes", Count = 1 }
```

Comment: I got as far as this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/491832/668521 but I am unsure about counting the number of times grouped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
people.GroupBy(x => new { x.Age, x.FirstName, x.LastName })
      .Select(x => new { x.Key.Age, x.Key.FirstName, x.Key.LastName, Count = x.Count() });
```

Comment: Should be `x.Key.Age`, `x.Key.LastName` and `x.Key.FirstName`?

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct. The code is corrected too. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just before I posted I saw answer already from JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow, so was going to cancel, but am posting anyway just to show same result using only the GroupBy, with the `resultSelector` parameter (instead of separate projection)

```
var personList = new List<Person> {
    new Person { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe" },
    new Person { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe" },
    new Person { Age = 10, FirstName = "James", LastName = "Dokes"}};

var results = personList.GroupBy(per => new { per.Age, per.FirstName, per.LastName },
    (key, items) => new { key.Age, key.FirstName, key.LastName, Count = items.Count() } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-proc alternative:

```
List<Person> ls = new List<Person>();
ls.Add (new Person() { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe" });
ls.Add(new Person() { Age = 20, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Joe" });
ls.Add(new Person() { Age = 10, FirstName = "James", LastName = "Dokes" });

var result = (from cur in ls
                group cur by new { Age = cur.Age, Name = cur.FirstName, LastName = cur.LastName }
                into tmpResult
                select new { tmpResult.Key.Age,tmpResult.Key.LastName,tmpResult.Key.Name,Count = tmpResult.Count()});
```